# JavaScript added HTML Form does not submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, mako

I want to add a form including an input text using javascript.
the adding works fine, but if i click the submit button nothing happens.
Here is the code:

```js
if (document.getElementById("run_name_query_box") == null) {
    var run_name_search = '<fieldset id="run_name_query_box">' +
        '<table> <td><tr>' +
        '<p style="font-size:16px"> Runname:</p>' +
        '<input type="text" style="font-size:16px" id="run_name">' +
        '<form method="post" action=query name="query_runname_name">' +
        '<input  style="font-size:14px"  value="Search Database" onclick= "run_name_querycreator()" id="search_run_name_id" type="submit" name="search_run_name_name"> ' +
        '</form>' +
        '</tr></td></table>' +
        '</fieldset>';
    $("#query_type_box").append(run_name_search);
}
```

the `run_name_querycreator()` function sets the value of the input.

I already use almost the same thing somewhere else and there it works:

```js
'<form method="post" action=query name="query">' +                                   
'<input style="font-size:14px" value = "Search Database" onclick = "combine_query()"  id="search" type="submit" name="search" >' +
'</form>'
```

If i copy the plain html part just into the main html body it works too.
This is all part of mako file used in a pyramid interface.

Comment: Check the console for errors in the `run_name_querycreator()` function.

Comment: where is the combine_query() function defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your HTML is malformed. I don't think a form element can be a child of a table element.

Your code should be like this,

```
var run_name_search = '<fieldset id="run_name_query_box">' +
    '<form method="post" action=query name="query_runname_name">' +
    '<table>'+
    '<tr><td>' +
    '<p style="font-size:16px"> Runname:</p>' +
    '<input type="text" style="font-size:16px" id="run_name">' +
    '<input  style="font-size:14px"  value="Search Database" onclick= "run_name_querycreator()" id="search_run_name_id" type="submit" name="search_run_name_name"> ';
$("#query_type_box").append(run_name_search);
```

This is your code generated HTML,

```
<fieldset id="run_name_query_box">
    <p style="font-size:16px">Runname:</p>
    <input style="font-size:16px" id="run_name" type="text">
    <input style="font-size:14px" value="Search Database" onclick="run_name_querycreator()" id="search_run_name_id" name="search_run_name_name" type="submit">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <form method="post" action="query" name="query_runname_name"></form>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

There is no form elements in within your `<form>`. (Including your form `submit` button). Then How it will work?

Your code should generate HTML like this to work,

```
<fieldset id="run_name_query_box">
    <form method="post" action="query" name="query_runname_name">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p style="font-size:16px">Runname:</p>
                        <input style="font-size:16px" id="run_name" type="text">
                        <input style="font-size:14px" value="Search Database" onclick="run_name_querycreator()" id="search_run_name_id" name="search_run_name_name" type="submit">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

See this <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/Y74cz/)**</kbd>

In this fiddle You can see **BEFORE FIX** section dynamic elements generated by you.
In **AFTER FIX** section you can see the correct html format.

FYI, When you are working with Dynamic html, Check you dynamically created html in developers tool.

Comment: getting the <form> out of the table worked perfectly!
Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/awesome/6hh8r/

Description: Added missing `onclick` function `run_name_querycreator()` in global namespace and connected it to [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) with apparent form data.

```
window.run_name_querycreator = function () {
    //alert($('#run_name').val());
    var x = '{"run_name":"' + $('#run_name') + '"}'

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: x,
        success: alert('success'),
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

$(function () {
    if (document.getElementById("run_name_query_box") === null) {
        var run_name_search = '<fieldset id="run_name_query_box">' +
            '<table> <td><tr>' +
            '<p style="font-size:16px"> Runname:</p>' +
            '<input type="text" style="font-size:16px" id="run_name">' +
            '<form method="post" action=query name="query_runname_name">' +
            '<input  style="font-size:14px" value="Search Database" onclick="run_name_querycreator()" id="search_run_name_id" type="submit" name="search_run_name_name"> ' +
            '</form>' +
            '</tr></td></table>' +
            '</fieldset>';
        $("#query_type_box").append(run_name_search);
        $form = $('[name="query_runname_name"]');
        $form.submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});
```